# Can't Create Dynamic Folder Name

Tags: c++

In C++ I want to create a dynamic folder each time I run my program.

```
#include <direct.h> // mkdir
#include <iostream> // std
#include <iomanip>  // put_time

int main(){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[40];
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    //strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S", timeinfo);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d_%m_%Y_%I_%M_%S", timeinfo);
    std::string path = "C:/example/";
    path.append(std::string(buffer));
    mkdir(path.c_str());
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

I want to create a folder named like `"Example/03_03_2016_20_22_26"`, but the code above will not create the folder I want.

If I remove the `path.append(std::string(buffer));` line, it will create the folder named `example` in my C directory.

However I want a folder named according to the complete date and time.

Where am I wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the full path name? Is there anything obvious in that? What if you use that to try and create the directory yourself within Windows?

Comment: Yeah I did print the full name, but I also tried this in Windows Visual Studio

Comment: What is the return value from `mkdir()`? This might tell you what's going on. Also, according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235326(v=vs.140).aspx), `mkdir()` is deprecated and it says you should use `_mkdir()`.

Comment: Debug it a little, first, what's the value of `path` after the call to `append`? What's the value of `buffer` after you call `strftime`? What's the actual result the program gives you?

Comment: @Steve Thanks for reminding, I should be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue is in the slash '/'.
On Windows better use the backslash. 
Try

```
  std::string path="C:\\example\\"
```

Comment: Good! I don't why I received a -1. I know the answer is not elegant, but it is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I use this code for a similar purpose in my project (`SAVE_DIR` is a macro definition):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream pathstr; // a convenient way to construct strings
std::time_t now = std::time(nullptr); // get the current time
// insert the required parts into the stream
pathstr << SAVE_DIR
        << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now), "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S") << ".png";
std::string path = pathstr.str(); // and the result as std::str
```

Output:

> /home/user/prog/render/rt/saves/2016_03_03_23_10_50.png

This has the benefit of being pure C++, though it may look a bit clumsy, depending on your taste.

As for what your code may fail, I'd watch the string values in a debugger first, and then save the return value of `mkdir()` and check it against the specifications: [POSIX `mkdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html).